# How to detect symbols and space in a Java String?

Tags: java, android, string

Is there any method in Java that can scan for symbols?
!@#$%^&*()-=|`~_,./;'[]<>?:"{}

I will use it to display an "Invalid Username" prompt after signing up with symbols and/or space (" ").

To clarify, I am using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular-expression. To match anything other than letter or number you could try `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`

Comment: ... hummm... that's not right... you should be doing the research on that yourself instead of asking others to hand over code to you on a plate - use google, countless of blog entries all over the internet will suffice... we're not here to do dirty work on your behalf at the expense of this person who took the time to suggest an answer. Really, you're either lazy or just a fly-by-nighter in the hope someone will do your homework!!!

Comment: We're not a search engine for you plain and simple.. to the OP, you did not indicate any slightest hint of an effort on your part and your response to lalith's answer is telling the whole picture... just saying :)

Comment: @JetPro Please look at java.lang.String#matches function to use the proposed solution.

Comment: Oh, sorry sir. I forgot to say that I'm a newbie programmer.

Comment: Ahhhh.. then why did you not say it in the first place... :( if you're a newbie programmer, great that you're learning, SO is not the resource as a stop-gap solution to copying paste from here... there's books you know, get the fundamentals of java first, then that would make things easier to navigate SO and understand the code that other helpers post...

Comment: Thank you, sir Sperumal. I've googled java.lang.String#matches, and I ended up here, http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at this [Documentation on Pattern and Matcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) from the Android Developers site.

An extract:

> Patterns are compiled regular expressions. In many cases, convenience
>   methods such as String.matches, String.replaceAll and String.split
>   will be preferable, but if you need to do a lot of work with the same
>   regular expression, it may be more efficient to compile it once and
>   reuse it. The Pattern class and its companion, Matcher, also offer
>   more functionality than the small amount exposed by String.

```
// Direct use of Pattern:
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
 Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
 boolean hasSpecialChars = m.find();
```

Then on `b` you will have the result of `inputString` containing non-alphanumeric characters.